# How to output Debug Information to a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, system.diagnostics

I'm creating an FTP client and I wish to output the responses to a RichTextBox by outputting the debug information.

Would anyone be able to help on how to do this? Thanks

```
public FileARK()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    hostAddress.Text = "host";
    UserName.Text = "foo";
    Password.Text = "bar";
    //FtpTrace.AddListener(new TextWriterTraceListener(responseWindow.Text));
   // Debug.WriteLine(responseWindow.Text);
}

private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn = new FtpClient();
    conn.Host = hostAddress.Text;
    conn.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName.Text, Password.Text);
    conn.Connect();


}

private void Disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Disconnect();
}

private void responseWindow_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: What the problem is?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have an ftp client created that can connect to an ftp server, I have the responses to the server being outputted in the debug window, but I'm wondering how to take the debug data and output it into a RichTextBox while the application is running.

Comment: Perhaps you should show us the code you have thus far..do a google search on how to use `Debug.WriteLine`

Comment: A RichTextBox may be overkill for what you want, but the property you'll want to call is myCoolRichTextBox.Document = myCoolDocument. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own [`TraceListener`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx) that gets configured in the app.config and dynamically tries to find a richtextbox that matches the name in the config.

Your class can look like this:

```
public class TextBoxListener : TraceListener
{
    RichTextBox _box;
    string _data;
    public TextBoxListener(string initializeData)
    {
        _data = initializeData;
    }

    private bool Init()
    {
        if (_box != null && _box.IsDisposed )
        {
            // back to null if the control is disposed
            _box = null;
        }
        // find the logger text box
        if (_box == null)
        {
            // open forms
            foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                // controls on those forms
                foreach (Control c in f.Controls)
                {
                    // does the name match 
                    if (c.Name == _data && c is RichTextBox)
                    {
                        // found one!
                        _box = (RichTextBox) c;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return _box != null && !_box.IsDisposed;
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        if (Init())
        {
            _box.Text = _box.Text + message + "\r\n";
        }
    }

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        if (Init())
        {
            _box.Text = _box.Text + message;
        }
    }
}
```

Most important part of this class is the `Init` method that iterates over all openforms and all controls to find an richtextbox control that matches the name that is configured in the app.config.

To make use of this class configure tracing in your app.config and [add a listener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfaf9h0e(v=vs.110).aspx)

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add name="box" 
             type="WindowsFormsApplication1.TextBoxListener, WindowsFormsApplication1" 
             initializeData="loggerRTB" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

The type is the fully qualified typename of your class (Namespace.Classname, AssemblyName) and in initializeData you'll add the name of your richtextbox control on your form. In my example app it is *loggerRTB*.

In your app you can use the standard `Trace` class now:

```
Trace.WriteLine("Hello world");
```

Notice that the `TextBoxListener` is only instantiated on the first call to `Trace.WriteLine`.

One of the benefits of this approach is the possibility to add multiple Listeners that write to different RichTextBox controls, even on separate forms (assuming those forms are open).

Comment: Thanking you for this!, I have everything working as I needed it :)